# Circular linked list with undeclared identifier error

Tags: c++, linked-list, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to construct a circular linked list that goes in intervals and deletes the node where it's lands. But I keep getting an undeclared identifier error. I can't seem where I can fix this error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node {                                
public:
   int data;                              
   Node *next;                                
   Node() {data = 0;next = NULL;}                  
   Node(int x) {data = x;next = NULL;}                 
   };
class CircularLinkedList {              
public:
   int addAtFront(Node *n);                            
   int isEmpty();                                  
   int addAtEnd(Node *n);                     
   CircularLinkedList() {head = NULL;}     
   Node *head;                               
   Node* search(int k);                            
   Node* deleteNode(int x);                            
};

int search(int x) {                                    
Node *ptr = head;                                   
while(ptr != NULL &&  ptr->data  != x) {             
    ptr = ptr->next;                                
}
return ptr;
}

int addAtFront(Node *n) {                                   
int i = 0;                                                 
 if(head == NULL) {   //error: undeclared identifier 'head'                                  
   n->next = head;                                                         
   head = n;       //error: undeclared identifier 'head'                                       
   i++;                                                                    
  }
 else {                                              
   n->next = head;             //error: undeclared identifier 'head'                       
   Node* last = getLastNode(); //error: undeclared identifier 'getLastNode'             
   last->next = n;                                 
   head = n;         //error: undeclared identifier 'head'                  
   i++;
   }
 return i;                                               
}

int deleteNode(int x) {               
  Node *n = search(x);  //error: Cannot initialize a variable  of type 'Node *' with an rvalue of type 'int'                                 
  Node *ptr = head;     //error: undeclared identifier 'head'          
     if(ptr == NULL) {                                       
       cout << "List is empty";
       return NULL;                                        
     }
    else if(ptr == n) {                                
        ptr->next = n->next;                           
        return n;
     }
    else {
      while(ptr->next != n) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
                    }
     ptr->next = n->next;
return n;
  }
 }

int main(){};
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Always add the text of the error message to your question. If this is Visual Studio copy the text from the Output tab instead of the errors tab.

Comment: Methods need to know that classes they belong in. Otherwise they are just  good ol' free functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Sorry about that. I edited it. Errors are in the comments made.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't have Visual Studio. I'm using xcode but, thanks for pointing that out. I made some comments stating the errors I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You have not properly qualified your member function definitions.

They must be prefixed with the class name, *i.e.*

```
int CircularLinkedList::addAtFront(Node *n)
{
    // ...
}
```

You may have other errors too.  I notice that your `search` function doesn't match the definition in the class (different return type).  And I wouldn't be surprised if you have other problems too.

Best advice I can give right now is *read the error message* -- it's trying to tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues :

a) The parameter head is undeclared identifier inside the methods `search`, `addAtFront`, `deleteNode`.

To fix this, you may define the functions declared in your class as `CircularLinkedList::search` instead of just `search` and refer to member `head` as `this->head`.

b) You need to define `getLastNode()`, it is missing